# Google sheets move focus from search box with keyboard shortcut

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I move focus from the search box back to the current (selected) cell using a keyboard shortcut? None of the pre-defined 'move focus' shortcuts appear to work. CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+M moves focus out of the search box, but to who knows where...

My macro to do this fails with 'Range not found'...

spreadsheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getActiveCell()).activate();

TIA.

Comment: If you use internal Spreadsheet tool 'Edit > Find and replace' `Ctrl+Shift+H` you can hit `Esc` to close this tool (you can't keep it open and get active a cell simultaneously, as far as I can tell). If you use standard browser's search `Ctrl+F` it depends on the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You can press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close the search box and make the last found cell the active cell. This works both in quick find <kbd>Control+F</kbd> and **Edit > Find and replace** <kbd>Control+Shift+H</kbd>.

To implement your own search function, you can use an `onEdit(e)` [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) like the one below.

The function uses a cell of your choice, say `A1`, as the search box. Choose **View > Freeze** to ensure the search box is always visible. Then enter the search string in the search box and press **Tab** to activate matching cells in the active sheet. You can also use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) as a search string.

```
/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user hand edits the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error('Please do not run the script in the script editor window. It runs automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet.');
  }
  quickFind_(e);
}

/**
* Finds cells that match the regular expression entered in a magic cell.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function quickFind_(e) {
  const sheets = /^(Sheet1|Sheet2|Sheet3)$/i; // use /./i to make the function work in all sheets
  const magicCell = 'A1';
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (!e.value
    || e.range.getA1Notation() !== magicCell
    || !sheet.getName().match(sheets)) {
    return;
  }
  let searchFor;
  try {
    searchFor = new RegExp(e.value, 'i');
  } catch (error) {
    searchFor = e.value.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
  }
  const magicCellR1C1 = 'R' + e.range.rowStart + 'C' + e.range.columnStart;
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  const matches = [];
  data
    .forEach((row, rowIndex) => row
      .forEach((value, columnIndex) => {
        if (value.match(searchFor)) {
          const cellR1C1 = 'R' + (rowIndex + 1) + 'C' + (columnIndex + 1);
          if (cellR1C1 !== magicCellR1C1) {
            matches.push(cellR1C1);
          }
        }
      }));
  if (matches.length) {
    sheet.getRangeList(matches).activate();
  }
}
```

Comment: Interestingly **Esc** simply removes focus from the searchbox, but doesn't return it to the active cell.  However I've realised that **Esc** **Esc** _will_ return focus to the active cell.

But what I _really_ want is to give focus to the cell the searchbox has just found (which is probably not the last active cell) but keep the searchbox visible for future searches of the same string.

(sorry, not clear how to format 'Esc' as a kbd character in Markdown; also, thanks to @Yuri)

Comment: I do not think that can be done with the built-in functionality of Google Sheets. Edited the answer to include an `onEdit(e)` function to do what you are asking for.