# Google sheets. Go to range depending on what a user has typed in a search box

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, search, goto

I know there is an option for going to a specific row in help by typing **go to range** or hitting **CTRL + F**, but I'm afraid my users won't bother with go to or CTRL+F search. Is there a script or function that could do the same as "go to specific row" a.k.a jump list depending on what the user has typed in a cell that serves as a search box?

Neither hlookup, vlookup, filter or search would do since the table travels way to the right. Plus, the users need to enter data when the row is found. The mentioned commands can only return value and do not allow data entry.

Script-wise I can't find even a hint where to start. Only played around with filter in this [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fI8PNWQMJ7K3gdXEvlhw3mEUrdio2DAe04_mo5QgLNk/edit?usp=sharing). The user basically enters search name or surname in C1 and ideally this should jump to a row. There are only 3 entries as this is a demo, but the original would be quite populated with data.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67555531/13045193) does the trick. Now trying to highlight it with the script below. The issue is, it highlights upon find and leaves the color when another search criteria is in the search box. I tried to remove highlighting. Any ideas?

```
if (matches.length) {
    sheet.getRangeList(matches).activate();
    sheet.getRangeList(matches).setBackground("yellow");
  }
   else if(matches != magicCell) {
    sheet.clearConditionalFormatRules();
    sheet.getRangeList(matches).setBackground("white");
   }
```

Comment: show what you tried and didn't work

Comment: script-wise nothing. As I can't find even a hint on where to start. I only played with filter command, which I added to the initial post.

Comment: Try the [quickFind_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67555531/13045193) script. It appears to do exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks. This works. Now trying to highlight it with 

if (matches.length) {
    sheet.getRangeList(matches).activate();
    sheet.getRangeList(matches).setBackground("yellow");
  }
   else if(matches != magicCell) {
    sheet.clearConditionalFormatRules();
    sheet.getRangeList(matches).setBackground("white");
   }

The issue is, it highlights upon find and leaves the color when another search criteria is in the search box. I tried to remove highlighting. Any ideas?

Comment: @LiepājasLiedagavidusskola Can you write an answer to the question so that it doesnt remain unanswered?

Answer (score 0):

Search box with highlight.
Change C1 below in the code to whatever your search box cell is. Set the script to run OnEdit in triggers. Change the offset to whatever number of rows you have that need to be excluded. Fix the header for ease.

Once found, all instances in the search box are set to background: yellow (change to whatever color you need). Once the search box is cleared, the yellow highlight disappears. Please note the following script takes from 1 to 4 seconds to execute. it is slower than CTRL + F, but it does a better highlight than CTRL + F. It allows users unfamiliar with CTRL + F, to search easily. Please also note, if the list contains multiple instances of whatever your search query, it will land on the last find. You would have to scroll manually to see all highlighted cells. It is, thus, less functional than CTRL + F.

**PS. If any Google employee reads this. I wish Google included a new Search box feature. Menu -> Insert -> Search box in a cell or over cells.**

Filtering doesn't suit my case since I have users at basic level of table knowledge. If they set a filter, they might not know how to turn it back off.

```
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user hand edits the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error('Please do not run the script in the script editor window. It runs automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet.');
  }
  quickFind_(e);
}

/**
* Finds cells that match the regular expression entered in a magic cell.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function quickFind_(e) {
  const sheets = /./i; // use /./i to make the function work in all sheets
  const magicCell = 'C1';
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
   if (e.range.getA1Notation() !== magicCell
    || !sheet.getName().match(sheets)) {
    return;
  }
  if (!e.value || !e.value.replace(/ +/g, '')) { clear_backgrounds(); return; }
  let searchFor;
  try {
    searchFor = new RegExp(e.value, 'i');
  } catch (error) {
    searchFor = e.value.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
  }
  const magicCellR1C1 = 'R' + e.range.rowStart + 'C' + e.range.columnStart;
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  const matches = [];
  data
    .forEach((row, rowIndex) => row
      .forEach((value, columnIndex) => {
        if (value.match(searchFor)) {
          const cellR1C1 = 'R' + (rowIndex + 1) + 'C' + (columnIndex + 1);
          if (cellR1C1 !== magicCellR1C1) {
            matches.push(cellR1C1);
          }
        }
      }));
      
  if (matches.length) {
    clear_backgrounds();
    sheet.getRangeList(matches).activate();
    sheet.getRangeList(matches).setBackground("yellow");
  }
  
 }

function clear_backgrounds() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange().offset(2,0); // offset to keep color of first 2 rows
  var bg = range.getValues();
  for (row in bg) for (col in bg[row]) bg[row][col] = null;
  range.setBackgrounds(bg);
}
```